# Why does not my javascript file apply to my HTML in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, hyperlink

I am working on a very simple ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2013. I added an HTML, a CSS and JS file(each empty). I created the links in between the the pages, and I put them into the same folder.

```
<head>
<title>Analog Clock</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

I figured out, that I didn't mispelt anything, but my js doesn't apply on the HTML.
My HTML body:

```
<svg width="140" height="140">
<circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
<line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
<line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
<line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
<line id="s-tail" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="56" />
<text x="62" y="18">12</text>
<text x="126" y="76">3</text>
<text x="66" y="130">6</text>
<text x="7" y="76">9</text>
</svg>
```

And my javascript is:

```
function setAttr(id, value) {
    var v = 'rotate(' + val + ',200,200);';
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', v);
};
setAttr('s-hand', 30);
```

I tried to drag it on my HTML page, but it doesn't make any difference(besides it puts it to the code:)

```
<script src="clockwork.js"></script>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Apologies for the dumb question, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 'rotate(' + val + ',200,200);' => val? or value?

Comment: sorry wrong typing, it is either value or val, but still not working

Comment: maybe it executes before the document is loaded, try placing it in the body onload (or jQ $(fn(){});

Comment: stick "alert('BLAH!');" in your javascript, and ensure it's firing before continuing. If it is, badness in your javascript. If it isn't then the javascript isn't even loading in the first. Also load in Chrome and hit F12. Look at the sources tab and ensure your javascript is loading in.

Comment: I tried the alert, but it hasn't worked, but come up with this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null. I can see the js file in the sources...